# Median filter with scipy.signal.medfilt

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals

Hello everyone I am currently working on applying a median filter on my data but when i apply the filter I got an error message :

```
Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py:1531: UserWarning: kernel_size exceeds volume extent: the volume will be zero-padded.
  warnings.warn('kernel_size exceeds volume extent: the volume will be
```

here is the code

```
torque is a numpy array

import numpy as np 
from scipy import signal

Torque=Torque_Middle_To_end[0:index]

filtered_data=signal.medfilt(Torque,5)
```

the length of Torque is +-= 570

start of data type of torque =

```
[0.27]
 [[0.25]
 [0.28]
 [0.28]
 [0.22]
..........
[6.68]
 [6.73]
 [6.82]
 [6.96]
 [7.06]]
```

When I print my filtered data, I got zeros only.
Any ideas ?
Thanks

I try to use my own "median filter" with numpy but when I go further than 3 as window lenght I got NaN

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning; the median filter still applies. Is the result not what you want ?

Comment: Hello it is not the content I want, I only got an array of length 570 fill with 0.

Comment: What does `Torque.shape` exactly return ?

Comment: it is :(1040, 1) so lenght 1040, 1 dim np array

Comment: Hey I solve it using the filter : nd.image_median_filter()

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using the  `ndimage.median_filter()`

Comment: Please click on "edit" and apply your edit there instead of comment section.

Comment: No, answers belong here in the answer section, not as question edits. However, this answer is currently low quality. Please include the actual code/explanation into your answer.

Comment: @tdy I didn't talk about editing the question. He/She had added some explanation to this answer in the comment section of this answer. So I asked him/her to edit the answer and include that explanation  as the part of the answer.